# If $f$ is an analytic function such that $fˆ2$ lies on the disc centered at $1$ of radius $1$ then either $Re(f(z))>0$ or $Re(f(z))<0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f: U \to \mathbb{C} $ be an analytic function , where $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$  is a region.  Show that if $ |  f ^{2}  (z) -1|<1$ for all  $z\in U$, then  either $Re(f(z))>0$ for all  $z\in U$ or $Re(f(z))<0$ for all  $z\in U$.

I can use theory about complex powers, inverse function theorem  and  Cauchy-Riemann equations but I don't know how to start, so any hint would  be  very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The condition guarantees that $f(z) \notin i\mathbb{R}$ for $z \in U$. So two open sets

$$A = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0\}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Re}(z) < 0\}$$

are disjoint and disconnect the image $f(U)$. But since $U$ is connected, so is $f(U)$. So we have either $f(U) \subset A$ or $f(U) \subset B$.

Comment: Now I see it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Suppose there exist $z_1,z_2\in U$ with $\text{Re}(f(z_1))>0$ and $\text{Re}(f(z_2))<0$. Take a path between $z_1$ and $z_2$ (why does a path exist between them?). By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is some $z_0$ on that path with $\text{Re}(f(z_0)) = 0$. So you would be done if you could show that it is impossible to have $\text{Re}(f(z)) = 0$ for any $z\in U$.

Now, if $\text{Re}(f(z)) = 0$, then what values can $f^2(z)$ take?

Comment: Oh, I'm interested about Intermediate Value Theorem on complex numbers, I didn't know it was valid. If $Re(f(z))=0$ then $fˆ2 $ takes the negative reals and $0$, which is impossible, thank you!

Comment: @user392559 what I meant by IVT is the following: notice that $\text{Re} f$ (taking $z$ to $\text{Re}(f(z))$) is a continuous function from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}$. A path between $z_1$ and $z_2$ is a continuous function $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow U$ such that $\gamma(0) = z_1$ and $\gamma(1) = z_2$. Now $\text{Re} f \circ\gamma$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which sends $0$ to something $>0$ and sends $1$ to something $<0$. Since it's a function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, we can apply the "usual" IVT from single variable calculus.

Comment: Oh, now I get it! thank you  so much !

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=u+iv$ with $u$ and $v$ real-valued.

For the proof below we do not need that $f$ is holomorphic. All we need ist that $u$ is continuous.

Suppose that there is some $z_0 \in U$ such that $u(z_0)=0$.

Then $f(z_0)^2= -v(z_0)^2$, hence $v(z_0)^2+1=|v(z_0)^2+1|=|-v(z_0)^2-1|=|f(z_0)^2-1|<1$. But then we have $v(z_0)^2<0$, a contradiction.

Thus we have shown that $u$ has no zeros. Since $u$ is continuous and $U$ is connected, we get that $I:=u(U)$ is an intervall in $ \mathbb R$ with $0 \notin I$.

The Intermediate Value Theorem shows the assertion.